# Accessing CheckBox in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How does one access the CheckBox.Checked value in an ASP.NET GridView? I want to select a bunch a records and then delete them.

What I've tried for testing is just to see if I can make the label change:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

C#

```
protected void Buttondelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   Label1.Text = "first";

   foreach (GridViewRow item in GridViewDelete.Rows)
   {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
       if (chk != null)
       {
           if (chk.Checked)
           {
               Label1.Text = "second";
           }
       }
    }     
}
```

I only get the "first" to go off.

Comment: I've deleted my anser as it appears your code should work.